# Free TextBox problem

Tags: javascript, css

i just can't get rid of such .... error
i'm using a free textbox control on my page that is hidden by setting css properties to "none" 
i want to make this free textbox available for edit whenever a user clicks on another 
button actually by setting style.. to "block" without postingback my page
the result is showing the textbox but in a way that it's not enabled 
i need some event to post back the page to make it available for edit
i know the reason should be something with rendering and etc but how can i solve this 
in a way i achieve my targets on page such as:no postbacks ,. ...

any hep would be appreciated
thank all

Comment: and why is it disabled? and what does the postback to enable it?

Comment: i just do'nt know the Answer for your Question.
you asked all i have written in just one sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()  {   
$("#buttontoclick").click(function() 
{
       $("#textboxtoshow").show(); 
});
```

html

```
<input id="buttontoclick" type="submit" Text="Click me" />

<input id="textboxtoshow" type="text" style="display: none" />
```